# How to make enemies pace back and forth pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, move

I made a sprite group and displayed them on the screen, but I don't know how to make them all move? I think I understand how to move one sprite as a class, but I have an entire group now. I want to have them pacing back and forth on the platforms (like left and right constantly). I know how to work with the movements of one sprite, but not a bunch in a group.

Here is what I have right now:

```
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('levoneplatform.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class LevOne():
    def __init__(self):

        self.background_image = pygame.image.load('night.png').convert_alpha()


        platforms_one = [ (200,300),
                        (50,500),
                        (550,650),
                        (300,200),
                        (120,100)
                   ]
        for k,v in platforms_one:
            platform = Platform()
            enemy = Enemy()
            platform.rect.x = k
            enemy.rect.x = k
            platform.rect.y = v
            enemy.rect.y = v - 44
            platform_list.add(platform)
            enemy_list.add(enemy)

    def update(self):
         screen.blit(self.background_image, [0, 0])

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

The rest is basically like my state changes and updates. I don't know how to move the entire sprite group. I know how to move one sprite, but not a bunch of sprites in one list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `update` method for the Sprite to make them move around. Then you can call the `enemy_list.update()` in order to make the update on each sprite in the group.

For reference check [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html).

Happy coding